# How to default NULL to Zero

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm creating sprocs with some calculations and I want to make sure I'm not missing something simple.

Say I'm finding a `SUM()` of a column that might have NULLs. Is there a single set statement that will convert `NULL` to Zero automatically without having to `COALESCE` each time? Or do I have to manually check for `NULL` each time?

I've looked through [MSDN SET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx) but I don't see anything useful.

There's a way to make `NULL` work with concatenation but I don't see anything for calculations.

For example:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON

--Calc
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(decimal(10,2), NULL))
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(decimal(10,2), Coalesce(NULL,0)))

--Concat
SELECT  NULL + ', ' + 'Isaak' AS Name
SELECT COALESCE(NULL + ', ' + 'Isaak','') AS Name
SELECT COALESCE(NULL,'') + ', ' + 'Isaak' AS Name

--Change Concat NULL to OFF
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF

--Calc
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(decimal(10,2), NULL))
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(decimal(10,2), Coalesce(NULL,0)))

--Concat
SELECT  NULL + ', ' + 'Isaak' AS Name
SELECT COALESCE(NULL + ', ' + 'Isaak','') AS Name
SELECT COALESCE(NULL,'') + ', ' + 'Isaak' AS Name
```

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs - Not when `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` is `OFF`. That is a deprecated option and there is no equivalent for addition.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs no, it won't. This is precisely what `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF;` will do.

Comment: Actually `SUM` does already work exactly the same as concatenation with that option on. `SELECT CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR) + CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR)` still returns `NULL`. The only way either would return `NULL` is if all inputs were `NULL`

Comment: @Jeremy yes I know. I was saying when you set that option OFF it won't.

Comment: @AaronBertrand OK yeah speed reading bit me here. :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve, but in general be careful about assuming that `NULL` can be replaced with zero. For `SUM()` it makes no difference, but `AVG()` will give a completely different result. In fact, since aggregate functions [ignore `NULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) anyway, I'm not sure what the point of substituting zero is in the first place. But your question seems to be mixing `NULL` aggregation and `NULL` concatenation, which are separate issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no magic way to do this. However there are multiple workarounds:

1. Stop allowing `NULL`s in the first place - add a default of 0 and if you can't update the DML logic then add a trigger (but far preferable to do this as part of the original insert/update).
2. Put the `COALESCE` into a view, and then reference the view in your queries.
3. Persist a zero (using `COALESCE` of course) into a separate, computed column, and change the calculation to use the computed column instead of the original column.

Comment: So should I stay away from `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF`?

Comment: @JIsaak - Yes. See [the warning here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms176056.aspx)

Comment: And `SELECT SUM(CONVERT(decimal(10,2), Coalesce(NULL,0)))` is perfectly acceptable?

Comment: Well I don't understand `COALESCE(NULL,0)` - do you mean `COALESCE(column_name,0)`?

Comment: Yes sir. Just assuming column_name is null

Comment: @JIsaak SUM is already eliminating null values. It will return NULL only if all values are NULL. You don't to use COALESCE on each row but only on result set. COALESCE(SUM(column_name),0) is better option.

Comment: If you're doing a `SUM` over a single column, sure. But what if it's an expression, e.g. `SUM(a + b)` and you want to include a when b is null and vice versa?